# Upadet Social Table Event Status using API function

Tags: social-tables

Is Any API function available in Social Table to update Event Status?
I have checked in api-console there is no function available to update Event.

Answer (score 0):

The ability to update Event status was added in our latest release and is now available through the existing PUT `/events/:event_id` endpoint.